# How do I display strings in VB.NET

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, split

I am trying to display the values of strings, but all i see in my output is System.String[] - which is pretty darned useless!

Here is my code:

```
    Dim pageOfText As String = SplitString(text, 750).ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(pageOfText.ToString)
```

Comment: `ToString()` is a method, so it needs the brackets to be included on the second line.

Comment: What's SplitString?  Looks like pageOfText should be an array, try declaring it as such.

Comment: @Psychemaster - no it doesn't VB.NET doesn't care whether you have brackets on methods or not

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on an array returns `System.String[]`. Don't call this and iterate the array.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing the implementation of the `SplitString` method this is an educated guess that `SplitString` returns a String *Array*.

You are using `.ToString` on this array which correctly returns `System.String[]` (Equivalent to `System.String()` in VB)

You should iterate through the strings in the array instead. Something like this:

```
For each s As String in SplitString(text, 750)
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess **SplitString** function split your text to **Integer** (750) pieces and store them as an array of String so if you want to display all of them iterate in the array

> For i as Integer to pageOfText.GetUpperBound(0)
>   Console.WriteLine("Trimmed text: " + pageOfText(i).toString() & Environment.NewLine) 
>   Next

And you can see all text in the page

hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could be trying for one of two things, so I will answer both:
(Note that I'm assuming `text` is your variable name.)

**1.** Try using the .NET function `String.Split` like this:

```
Dim strSplitString = text.Split(";"c)
For Each strOutput In strSplitString
    Console.WriteLine(strOutput)
Next
```

To use `String.Split`, use the `Split` method of the string you want to split and pass the character you want to use as the separator as an argument. This produces a string array that you can then irritate through with `For Each . . .`

Note that if you want `String.Split` to accept a string as a separator, you must also specify how many strings it may include and whether it may include blank strings.

```
Dim strSplitString = text.Split("750", 750, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

**2.** Try using the .NET function `String.SubString` to retrieve the first 750 characters of your string.

```
Dim strSplitString = text.SubString(0, 750)
Console.WriteLine(strSplitString)
```